# How to access attributes in an array Php/Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I have this array(image1) and I want to access the priority atribute and the item->desc , item->qtd ,etc

So I want to know how can I do that.

im using laravel 7 , Thats my code :

```
                 <?php 

                   $json=($pedidoInfo); //$pedidoInfo is coming from my controller ->
                                       //($pedidoInfo=Pedidos::Get('pedidoInfo'))
                                       //'pedidoInfo' is a json in my database
                   foreach ($json as $key => $value){

                   echo '<pre>';   var_dump ($value->pedidoInfo);echo '<pre>';


                              }

                 ?>
```

I've tried to use $value->pedidoInfo->priority and $value->pedidoInfo['priority'] but no luck.

(array printed in $value->pedidoInfo)

[image: image1]

Comment: You have some quoting issue there. Check in DB if key is `"'priority'"`, if so it should've been saved as `"priority"` in first place.

Comment: you are right my db is saving  " 'example ' "  , i will see why

Comment: just figure out that i was saving a input like this name=['priority'] ,so i just remove the ' ' , hope this will solve my problem

Comment: @Tpojka  you were right , solved my problem ! !! thanks for the help !!!

Answer (score 1):

IF "array printed in $value->pedidoInfo"
You try  $value->pedidoInfo[**index**]->**attr**
Or use foreach to loop array

Comment: if i put $value->pedidoInfo[0]->priority = returns Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: Yes, Because, I see in the picture that an array contains objects :((